# How to simplify floor polynomial given lower bound on x?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$
\left\lfloor\frac{8x^2 + 5x -4}{3x^2 + x}\right\rfloor
$$

where $x$ > $\sqrt{8}$

How would you simplify this type of expression?

*Please note the floor operation surrounding the expression

Simplified further after user suggestion:

$$
\left\lfloor\frac{8 + 5\frac{1}{x} - \frac{4}{x^2}}{3 + \frac{1}{x}}\right\rfloor
$$

Comment: divide every term by $x^2;$ this changes nothing

Comment: what changes nothing?

Comment: Inside the floor symbols, divide numerator and denominator by $x^2.$ This is exactly the same numerically, but should suggest something about the value of the floor of it.

Comment: Ok, did that... I think

Comment: I'm still not seeing where to go with this

Comment: The question asks for the value of the expression when $x\gt \sqrt8$.  This includes, for example, when $x=1000000$.  Without doing any detailed calculations, can you look at the expression and guess what its value will be when $x=1000000$?

Comment: No, I'm really not seeing this. I've tried plugging in various values and it doesn't ultimately end up being any specific number. I can't see what you mean by plugging in x = 1,000,000. I mean, I understand that you're trying to hint towards something about the expression, but I'm not seeing it..

Comment: The point is that you insert some arbitrary high number for $x$ and see what happens. When $x$ is a very high number, the expression equals approximately the floor function of $(8+0-0)/(3+0) = 8/3$, which is $2$. What about when $x=\sqrt{8}$? Does your expression decrease on the interval $]\sqrt{8}, \infty[$?

Answer (score 0):

The partial fraction is $\frac83 -\frac{4}{x}+\frac{43}{3(3x+1)}$ and the second and third term are rigidly bound if $x$ is larger than some minimum.